# Django: Managing urls like id:slug with duplicated slug

Tags: django, url, django-urls, slug

Using Django 1.5 I am storing the slug in DB

I configured my urls like follows:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+):(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', TracksDetailView.as_view(), name="track-view"),
```

And in my podel I have:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('track-view', [str(self.id), str(self.slug)])
```

If 2 slugs are the same I get the following error:

```
get() returned more than one GPXTrack -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {}
```

I use a generic view (DetailView) to render the page:

```
class TracksDetailView(DetailView):
    model = GPXTrack
    context_object_name = 'track'
```

Any idea on how to avoid this **without needing unique slugs**?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the URL, it's the code that gets the GPXTrack (and returns the error). Perhaps you'd better show that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I just update the question providing the code

Comment: Well, lets say I'm a user with `id = 1523` and I make two `tracks` (whatever that is) and let's say I name both `monkeyTrack` how does your application know which one I want if I access `yourApp.com/1/monkeyTrack`, you need to have the slugs unique or limit the users somehow if you want to avoid this error!

Comment: I retrieve the track by id rather than slug given that id is unique: id refers to the track id not the user id

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to override your view's `get_object` method.  The one you're inheriting does not take into account that you're using the ID and slug.  It assumes you're passing either a pk or a slug - and also assumes they're unique.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was simple but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Well the method [get_object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L19) looks for a kwargs with key 'pk' rather than 'id', therefore I changed my urls to:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+):(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', TracksDetailView.as_view(), name="track-view"),
```

And everything worked fine!